# IIS (Internet Information Services) not working on Windows 10

Tags: iis

I have been having problems with my Windows 10 (for example my `localhost:8000`). So I started looking for an answer, and it looks like the good old IIS is causing this issue, maybe because it's not enable in the turn Windows features on/off. SO in theory it should be a piece of cake right? Well when I click next I get the following message:

> Windows couldn't complete the requested changes.
>         The function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another         transaction. Error code: 0x80071A90

I read somewhere that it may be related to the .NET Framework, I have Framework 3.5 and 4.6 installed. I have tried all possible combinations, enable both of them, disable both, only one, everything! Not real information around regarding the Error code either.

Does it have something to do with the version of Windows that I have? Which is Windows Home. Is there any other way to make it work? Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: From where did you get this error message?

Comment: From the Turn windows features on/off

Comment: Windows 10 does not have a Home edition if I remember correctly.

Comment: I have Windows 10 Home installed. Unfortunately I don't have enough points to attach a picture. Anyway, the thing is it doesn't get installed the way it should get installed. Any ideas?

Comment: @LexLi Windows 10 has 2 versions home and pro same as windows 8

Answer (score 80):

As this is one of the first hits when you search for that error message posting solution here...

If you get this error when trying to "Turn Windows features on or off" in Windows 10 - make sure to disable Antivirus program.

Culprit for me was Avast.

To disable Avast right click on the icon in task-bar -> Avast shields control -> Disable until computer is restarted.

After Avast was disabled I had no problems with adding new features.

Comment: 1 UP - Thanks Man never though AVAST AV would block a windows system

Comment: You saved me hours of work....had I seen this post earlier, I would have saved more time...

Comment: I wish I could double up-vote. I got " the function attempted to use the name that is reserved for use by another transaction" error trying to install IIS and disabling AVAST shields control allowed me to continue.

Comment: This also resolved my issue with McAfee OAS, I just disabled it during the install

Comment: Suggestion for all future Microsoft problems: just open StackOverflow instead of losing time with the MS support site. The KB linked to the error does not help (and some link in that page exist no more...).

Comment: Works. In my case wasn't Avast, but AVG.